# FSharp.Data HTTP request - unable to set request timeout

Tags: f#, f#-data

We have a simple F# console app that sends a HTTP POST request to a WebAPI endpoint via `FSharp.Data Http.Request`. We are using the `customizeHttpRequest` parameter in order to try to set the request timeout property.  Our usage is as follows:

```
let response = Http.Request(
    serviceEndpoint,
    headers = requestHeaders,
    body = requestBody,
    silentHttpErrors = true,
    customizeHttpRequest = (fun request -> request.Timeout <- 1000; request))
```

We are observing that our custom timeout is ignored (i.e. the request does not timeout after 1 second as in this example). We have also observed that the request will not timeout after the default `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` timeout of 100,000ms.

Is there an issue here, or are we not using the `customizeHttpRequest` parameter correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FSharp.Data uses the asynchronous `GetResponse` method. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx), in that case the timeout set on the `HttpWebRequest` object isn't considered and handling the timeout is left for the client code to implement.

Unfortunately FSharp.Data doesn't do it. There's an open issue for implementing it [here](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/issues/802).

Comment: The issue was implemented and closed